# Web Parallax Scrolling Background Image and Text

Tags: css, background, scroll, z-index, parallax

Fiddle of the issue: **http://jsfiddle.net/Vy365/3/**

I'm trying to create sections on a page that have a parallax scrolling effect.

The main CSS I'm using to achieve this is `background-attachment: fixed` for the background image, and `position: fixed` for the text on top of the image.

I have multiple div's with this effect on the page, and I want each section to cover up those that come before it.

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <div id="parallax-1" class="parallax">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Fixed Text 1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="scrolling-content">Scrolling Content</section>

<section>
    <div id="parallax-2" class="parallax">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Second Fixed Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="scrolling-content">Scrolling Content</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parallax {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.parallax .title {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
}

#parallax-1 {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500/200);
}

#parallax-2 {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500/202);
}

.scrolling-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ffffff;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The background images cover up one another appropriately, however the fixed text remains fixed on the page (once again, see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vy365/3/)).

Is there any way to fix this with CSS? Or do I have to do some yucky jquery window scroll monitoring?

Answer (score 1):

Think you want to use position:absolute instead of position:fixed on your '.parallax .title' class

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery anyway, why don't you try a plug in like http://stephband.info/jparallax/ ?

**EDIT**: For mobile apps, you may want to check out [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).  It is pure Javascript, and there are some really good examples in the "In the wild" section.

It can help you from re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: is there a good way to get that plugin working with simple background images + text? seems to want to do a lot of things i don't want like track the mouse and stuff, which I'm worried may not be mobile compatible

Comment: This plug-in does have concerns with scrolling on mobile.  I updated the Skrollr link, which does work well with mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two tutorials (both using Skrollr.js) which might help others trying to create a similar parallax scrolling effect.

- [How to create a parallax scrolling website](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/)
- [Simple parallax scrolling tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)